# Attach a property to the global req object in the middleware and use it in a controller with concurrent client requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, concurrency

I have this middleware

```
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  if (token) {
    //Se il token esiste devo comunque verificare che sia valido
    try {
      const payload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = { userId: payload.userId, name: payload.name };
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      throw new UnauthenticatedError(
        "You have to login to access protected area"
      );
      //next(error);
    }
  } else {
    //token non esiste
    throw new UnauthenticatedError(
      "You have to login to access protected area"
    );
  }
};

export { isAuthenticated };
```

and this controller:

```
  const createJob = async (req, res) => {
     
      //res.send(req.user);
      const jobCreated = await jobModel.create(
        [{ ...req.body, createdBy: req.user.userId }],
        {
          sanitizeFilter: true,
        }
      );
      res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).send(jobCreated[0]);
    };
```

In my routes I have

```
router.route("/").post(isAuthenticated , createJob)
```

I'm using the middleware before the controller to check if the user can access the protected route (with a jwt token inside a cookie)

My question is:
Is sure attach user in req.user in the middleware isAuthenticated?  req is a global object shared by all requests. If another request comes (another client) (before `JobModel.create()` is called)  can overwrite the user property on the req of the previous request before `await jobModel.create` is executed (thus obtaining erroneous results)?